# Trying to use contains to search for a string of text

Tags: html, xpath

I'm trying to check for some text ("dateFormat") on a page...

this is my html:

```
<div id="RsWidget" style="margin-top: 5px; margin:auto auto;">

<script src="dateFormat=dd-MM-yyyy" type="text/javascript"/>
```

I can get as far as the text line which is highlighted (script src) by doing:

```
.//*[@id='rswidget']/script[1]
```

Now, I just need to be able to do a check that it contains the text "dateFormat".

I've tried  `.//*[@id='rswidget']/script[1]` and `contains(., 'dateFormat')`

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about xpath?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `and` after the query, or you would and`the value returned by the query, which does not make any sense for a matched node. You need to put it in the`[]`condition. Also`.` returns the text content, not the src attribute (although having a format in the attribute does not make much sense as well).

Therefore use:

```
.//*[@id='rswidget']/script[1][contains(@src, 'dateFormat')]
```